# Which phrase is possible using "last time"?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is a dialogue:

> "Which hotel are you staying?"
>   "It's the same hotel I stayed at last time I was here."

I'd like to ask about the second sentence. If I want to make it short, which sentence is correct from the following?

- (1) It's the same hotel I stayed at last time.
- (2) It's the same hotel I last stayed at.
- (3) It's the same hotel I stayed at for the last time.

Or do I always have to say the full sentence like the first example even in the daily conversation?

Comment: Also note that your first sentence has a mistake: it should read "Which hotel are you staying ***at***?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In casual conversation, you don't need a complete grammatical sentence. I'd be inclined to shorten it like this:

> Same one as last time.

There are a number of similar variations that might slip out as well:

> Same hotel as last visit.
>   The same place as last time.
>   Some one I stayed at before.
>   I'm staying where I did before.

Comment: Sounds very natural and simple. Thank you very much. Sometimes shortened sentences like these are difficult to make.

Answer (score 1):

I think (1) is the most appropriate.
(3) is improper because "for the last time" means really that was the last time you decided to be at that hotel, so you would never return to that place.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that.  I didn't know that. It was very helpful.